# How to ignore DuplicateKeyException and set BindingResult instead without try-catch block

Tags: java, spring-boot

For my Spring Boot web app project. I have the data registration service and I need to show an error on the web screen in the case of ***DuplicateKeyException*** occurs. I want to reject the error message via ***BindingResult***. The simple way is used try-catch block like this

```
try {
    // Insert logic.
catch (DuplicateKeyException e) {
    bindingResult.reject("ERROR01"); //error code mapping to message in properties file.
}
```

But I don't want to add this try-catch block to every insert logic. How to write this logic as a common class. I have researched about ControllerAdvice and AOP but I can't get a proper solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

You have researched correct. `ControllerAdvice` is handy in Spring framework to handle application wide exceptions. Using `ControllerAdvice` you do not need to handle the exceptions using try-catch, but they will be handled by the `ControllerAdvice` and will return the response with proper error message. Below is the short example of how you can create ControllerAdvice:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
/** Provides handling for exceptions throughout this service. */
@ExceptionHandler({ DuplicateKeyException.class })
public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
    // handle the exception here
    // prepare proper error object
    // return it
}
```

If you want to read more on `ControllerAdvice`, here is the link for it - https://medium.com/@jovannypcg/understanding-springs-controlleradvice-cd96a364033f